# How to write numbers in scientific notation in R

Tags: r, xtable

I am wondering if there is a way to write 0.000523 in scientific notation ( `5.23x10-4`) in `R`. I am using the `xtable` command to write a table into `latex`.

Comment: `format(x, scientific = T)` gives `1] "5.23e-04"`

Comment: You can use `options(scipen = -15)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sprintf` like this:

```
x <- c(0.000523, -523)

sprintf("%.2fx10^{%d}", 
        x/10^floor(log10(abs(x))), 
        floor(log10(abs(x))))
#[1] "5.23x10^{-4}" "-5.23x10^{2}"
```

You'll need to write some `ifelse` conditions to have different formatting depending on the decimal ranges.

Comment: what about `gsub("e", "x10^", format(scientific = T, x))` giving `5.23x10^-04`. though not logically sound step

Answer (score 4):

The `xtable` package offers the function `sanitize.numbers()` that can do this. It works on characters, so you first have to use `format()` to convert your numbers to characters:

```
library(xtable)
sanitize.numbers(format(0.000523, scientific = TRUE),
                 type = "latex", math.style.exponents = TRUE)
## [1] "$5.23 \\times 10^{-4}$"
```

As you notice, this does not give `5.23x10^-4` but rather the equivalent of this expression in LaTeX notation, which may not be what you needed.